# Position a number on the position of another number on a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have created two functions that generate a 5x5 grid and inside of this grid two number,1 and 2, are placed. The number 1 is placed somewhere random and number 2 is placed at (4,0). The code that creates the position of number 1 is:

```
 public void numberOnePosition(){
    locations = new int[x][y]; 
    Random randomPosition = new Random(); 
    int xPosition = randomPosition.nextInt(4)+1;
    int yPosition = randomPosition.nextInt(4)+1;
    locations[xPosition][yPosition] = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<y; j++){
            System.out.printf("%5d", locations[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The code that generates the position of number 2 is:

```
 public void numberTwoPosition() {
        locations[4][0] = 2;
        System.out.println("The position of 2 is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d", locations[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Let me mention I have created those private fields:

```
private int x = 5;
private int y = 5;
private int[][] locations;
```

However I want to create a third method ,called **MoveAtPositionOfTwo**, that moves number "1" at the position of number "2". Is there any way I could do it? Also, would it be easier if I use setters and getters?
Thank you

Comment: If you planned on manipulating x and y then certainly getters and setters would help, but you haven't clarified what you're overall trying to accomplish with this class. To copy the position, browse the array for the position of 1(using loops), or just store the random positions when you make them in class variables instead of in the method scope variables that you could call in your new method. You should keep class variables for holding the positions of 1 and 2 if you need to manipulate them.

Comment: @Alias Cartellano The whole idea is to use the Djikstra algorithm inside the **MoveAtPositionOfTwo**. However that is not my concern.I have already implemented the Djikstra somewhere else and I would just use.My main issue is whether I should use setters and getters and if so how can I accomplish that. For example how do I create a setter and getter the the field location and how do I use them inside those other two mentioned methods?Like instead of using **locations[4][0] = 2;** how do I do it with setters and getters?

Comment: If 2 has to be at that exact position then you wouldn't need getters and setters to manipulate that. To make a setter you need to create a method in your class that sets the value of one of the fields(eg. x) by accepting a parameter(int). Getters simply return field values(eg.a getter would return x). To hold a position of one variable make two position int variables (eg.`xPositionOne` and `yPositionOne`) and you can do similarly for two and make setters for both pairs. To set the location of two or one in your methods use what I previously mentioned.

Comment: If you mean to set the position of y with one method only then pass in parameters `int x` and `int y` in your method in your main, modify your method to accept them, and use **locations[x][y]=2** to set 2.